# Django - replace parts of urlfield

Tags: python, django, youtube

I can now load single video URLs of youtube. But the problem now is to load the playlist videos of youtube. So my question is, how do I replace two same pattern, but both having different replacements of a url?

Eg:

Actual url:

```
<iframe width="400" height="327" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1UiICgvrsFI&amp;list=PLvAOICvbvsbnc5dLG0YR9Mq_tFfzAhQSp&amp;index=1" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Replace the pattern to become like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1UiICgvrsFI?list=PLvAOICvbvsbnc5dLG0YR9Mq_tFfzAhQSp" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here the first `&amp;` changes to `?` and the second `&amp;` and its following contents i.e. `&amp;index=1` are stripped.

This is the models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video_url = models.URLField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_url = (self.video_url.replace("watch?v=","v/"))
        super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if new_url:
            self.video_url = new_url
```

**Edit:**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_url = re.sub('watch\?v=','embed/',self.video_url)
        new_url = re.sub(r'^(http:\/\/)([\w\W]+)\&amp;list=([\w\W]+)(\&amp;index=[\d]+)$', r'//\2?list=\3', new_url)
        if new_url:
            self.video_url = new_url
            super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it seems to be that your url is encoded. Please check if you don't have `|urlencode` filter in your template (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode).

To change video URL to playlist URL, you have to use regular expressions. You can create a method which will transform your video URL to playlist URL:

```
import re
...
def playlist_url(self):
    """
    Generates a playlist URL
    """
    new_url = re.sub(r'^(http:\/\/)([\w\W]+)&list=([\w\W]+)(\&index=[\d]+)$', r'//\2?list=\3', self.video_url)
    return new_url
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it, but there's still a `&` in the url. Would you please show me how to do it in regex? And please note that index=1 may vary. Thanks again.

Comment: There's still a `&` in the url and `http://`:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/1UiICgvrsFI`&`list=PLvAOICvbvsbnc5dLG0YR9Mq_tFfzAhQSp

Comment: It does work in the console, but I can't seem to work in my project... Will you please take a look at the edit, I have added your snippet too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTMLParser.unescape` function for unescaping url:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
h.unescape("http://www.youtube.com/embed/1UiICgvrsFI&amp;list=PLvAOICvbvsbnc5dLG0YR9Mq_tFfzAhQSp&amp;index=1")
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/1UiICgvrsFI&list=PLvAOICvbvsbnc5dLG0YR9Mq_tFfzAhQSp&index=1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please note that urls may vary according to the users upload.

Comment: @Robin what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But I also want to remove `&` and `&index=...`.

Comment: @Robin use urlstring.replace('&index=1', '') or regexp sub function